# Creating a panel data frame based on two other dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, panel-data

I have two data frames:

```
ANNUALSALARY <- structure(list(FIRM = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), SLY_ADMIN = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), SLY_MKT = c(0.5, 0.003,0.3), SLY_FIN = c(0.11, 0.12, 0.03)), .Names = c("FIRM", "SLY_ADMIN", "SLY_MKT", "SLY_FIN"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

and:

```
WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY <- structure(list(FIRM = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), WEEKS = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), PR_ADMIN = c(1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5), Z_ADMIN = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), PR_MKT = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2), Z_MKT = c(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4), PR_FIN = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), Z_FIN = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), .Names = c("FIRM", "WEEKS", "PR_ADMIN", "Z_ADMIN", "PR_MKT", "Z_MKT", "PR_FIN", "Z_FIN"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = c("plm.dim", "data.frame"))
```

I am interested in creating a data frame that takes minimum out of `SLY_ADMIN`, `SLY_MKT`, and `SLY_FIN` for each `FIRM`. Then takes the corresponding value out of  `PR_ADMIN`, `PR_MKT`, and `PR_FIN` as well as ot of `Z_ADMIN`, `Z_MKT`, and `Z_FIN`. e.g. if `SLY_MKT` is minimum for FIRM A then it returns the `PR_MKT` and `Z_MKT` for 5 WEEKS. The panel data frame would look like this (I have created it manually):

```
REQUIRED <- structure(list(FIRM = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"),WEEKS = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), PR = c(1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), MIN_SLY = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03), SLY_DEPT = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("SLY_ADMIN", "SLY_FIN", "SLY_MKT"), class = "factor"), Z = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), .Names = c("FIRM", "WEEKS", "PR", "MIN_SLY", "SLY_DEPT", "Z"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = c("plm.dim", "data.frame"))
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Get the index of the minimum value of the numeric columns in the "ANNUALSALARY" using `max.col`.  Then, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' and `melt` it from 'wide' to 'long' format, get the "MIN_SLY" and "S

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- max.col(-1*ANNUALSALARY[-1])
dN <- melt(setDT(ANNUALSALARY), id.var = "FIRM", value.name = "MIN_SLY", 
   variable.name = "SLY_DEPT")[ , .SD[which.min(MIN_SLY)], by = FIRM]
setDT(WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY)
```

Or instead of `melt`ing, we can create the 'data.table' using the 'i1'

```
dN <- data.table(FIRM= ANNUALSALARY$FIRM, 
                MIN_SLY=as.data.frame(ANNUALSALARY)[-1][cbind(1:nrow(ANNUALSALARY), i1)], 
                SLY_DEPT = names(ANNUALSALARY)[-1][i1])
```

Then, we `join` the 'dN' by 'WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY' and `melt` to 'long' format based on the `patterns` in column names.  We `order` by 'FIRM', 'variable', 'WEEKS', create a grouping variable ('gr1') based on the "WEEKS" value, grouped by 'FIRM'.

```
dN2 <- melt(dN[WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY, on = "FIRM"], measure = patterns("^PR", "^Z"), 
    value.name = c("PR", "Z"))[order(FIRM, variable, WEEKS)
       ][, gr1 := cumsum(WEEKS==1), FIRM][]
```

Finally, we join with a data.table' created using 'i1', `on` "FIRM", subset the rows where 'gr1' is equal to 'i1', and select the columns of interest.

```
res <- data.table(FIRM= ANNUALSALARY$FIRM, i1)[dN2, on = "FIRM"
            ][gr1==i1][,names(REQUIRED), with = FALSE]

all.equal(as.data.frame(res), REQUIRED, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
res
#    FIRM WEEKS PR MIN_SLY  SLY_DEPT Z
# 1:    A     1  1   0.100 SLY_ADMIN 1
# 2:    A     2  5   0.100 SLY_ADMIN 2
# 3:    A     3  4   0.100 SLY_ADMIN 3
# 4:    A     4  3   0.100 SLY_ADMIN 4
# 5:    A     5  2   0.100 SLY_ADMIN 5
# 6:    B     1  5   0.003   SLY_MKT 4
# 7:    B     2  0   0.003   SLY_MKT 3
# 8:    B     3  1   0.003   SLY_MKT 2
# 9:    B     4  2   0.003   SLY_MKT 1
#10:    B     5  3   0.003   SLY_MKT 9
#11:    C     1  5   0.030   SLY_FIN 1
#12:    C     2  4   0.030   SLY_FIN 2
#13:    C     3  3   0.030   SLY_FIN 3
#14:    C     4  2   0.030   SLY_FIN 4
#15:    C     5  1   0.030   SLY_FIN 5
```

Comment: when I run the dN2 line :Error in `[.data.table`(dN, WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY, on = "FIRM") : 
  logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.

Comment: @PolarBear  I am not getting any error.  I use `data.table_1.9.6`

Answer (score 3):

A different approach, but also using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
# convert the dataframes to datatables (which is an enhanced form of dataframe)
setDT(ANNUALSALARY)
setDT(WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY)

# join them on 'FIRM'
res <- WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY[ANNUALSALARY, on = 'FIRM']
# create a convenience vector with the columnnames starting with 'SLY_
sly.cols <- grep('^SLY_', names(res), value = TRUE)

# create the 'MIN_SLY' & 'SLY_DEPT' columns
res[, `:=` (MIN_SLY = min(.SD),
            SLY_DEPT = sly.cols[which.min(.SD)]), 
    by = 1:nrow(res), .SDcols = sly.cols][]

# melt it in log format and create the 'PR' & 'Z' column
res2 <- melt(res, id = c('FIRM','WEEKS','MIN_SLY','SLY_DEPT'), 
             measure.vars = patterns('^PR_','^Z_'),
             value.name = c('PR','Z'))[, variable := c('ADMIN','MKT','FIN')[variable]
                                       ][, `:=` (PR = PR[sub('^SLY_','',SLY_DEPT) == variable],
                                                 Z = Z[sub('^SLY_','',SLY_DEPT) == variable]), 
                                         by = .(FIRM,WEEKS)
                                         ][, variable := NULL]

# removing the duplicates
res2 <- res2[!duplicated(res2)]
```

which results in:

```
> res2
    FIRM WEEKS MIN_SLY  SLY_DEPT PR Z
 1:    A     1   0.100 SLY_ADMIN  1 1
 2:    A     2   0.100 SLY_ADMIN  5 2
 3:    A     3   0.100 SLY_ADMIN  4 3
 4:    A     4   0.100 SLY_ADMIN  3 4
 5:    A     5   0.100 SLY_ADMIN  2 5
 6:    B     1   0.003   SLY_MKT  5 4
 7:    B     2   0.003   SLY_MKT  0 3
 8:    B     3   0.003   SLY_MKT  1 2
 9:    B     4   0.003   SLY_MKT  2 1
10:    B     5   0.003   SLY_MKT  3 9
11:    C     1   0.030   SLY_FIN  5 1
12:    C     2   0.030   SLY_FIN  4 2
13:    C     3   0.030   SLY_FIN  3 3
14:    C     4   0.030   SLY_FIN  2 4
15:    C     5   0.030   SLY_FIN  1 5
```

Comment: Thanks. This is beautiful and a bit simpler.

Comment: do you know  any known issues when datatables are used with plm package?

Comment: @PolarBear I never used that package before. Have you run into a problem with it? If so, it's probaly best to ask a new question.

Comment: Please have a look at this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293841/r-matching-aggregate-values-with-daily-values-by-repetition

Comment: @PolarBear If you think that question is not a duplicate: I can reopen it, but you will have to undelete it first.

Comment: Thanks. Since I have deleted it , I am posting link to the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313500/rrepeating-aggregate-values-for-daily-values-in-a-panel-setting

Answer (score 2):

This was a tricky problem! I've come up with a base R solution built around `max.col()`, `merge()`, and index matrices.

Note that for concision I used the variable names `sal` and `prod`.

```
sufs <- c('ADMIN','MKT','FIN');
slys <- paste0('SLY_',sufs);
mins <- max.col(-sal[slys]);
res <- merge(prod[,c('FIRM','WEEKS')],cbind(sal[,'FIRM',drop=F],SLY_DEPT=slys[mins],MIN_SLY=sal[slys][cbind(seq_len(nrow(sal)),mins)]));
res.sufs <- sub('.*_','',res$SLY_DEPT);
for (pre in c('PR','Z')) { pre.cns <- paste0(pre,'_',sufs); res[[pre]] <- prod[pre.cns][cbind(seq_len(nrow(prod)),match(paste0(pre,'_',res.sufs),pre.cns))]; };

res;
##    FIRM WEEKS  SLY_DEPT MIN_SLY PR Z
## 1     A     1 SLY_ADMIN   0.100  1 1
## 2     A     2 SLY_ADMIN   0.100  5 2
## 3     A     3 SLY_ADMIN   0.100  4 3
## 4     A     4 SLY_ADMIN   0.100  3 4
## 5     A     5 SLY_ADMIN   0.100  2 5
## 6     B     1   SLY_MKT   0.003  5 4
## 7     B     2   SLY_MKT   0.003  0 3
## 8     B     3   SLY_MKT   0.003  1 2
## 9     B     4   SLY_MKT   0.003  2 1
## 10    B     5   SLY_MKT   0.003  3 9
## 11    C     1   SLY_FIN   0.030  5 1
## 12    C     2   SLY_FIN   0.030  4 2
## 13    C     3   SLY_FIN   0.030  3 3
## 14    C     4   SLY_FIN   0.030  2 4
## 15    C     5   SLY_FIN   0.030  1 5
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
## libraries
library(data.table);
library(microbenchmark);

## define inputs, including data.table instances for akrun and maximus solutions
sal <- structure(list(FIRM = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), SLY_ADMIN = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), SLY_MKT = c(0.5, 0.003,0.3), SLY_FIN = c(0.11, 0.12, 0.03)), .Names = c("FIRM", "SLY_ADMIN", "SLY_MKT", "SLY_FIN"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame");
prod <- structure(list(FIRM = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), WEEKS = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), PR_ADMIN = c(1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5), Z_ADMIN = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), PR_MKT = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2), Z_MKT = c(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4), PR_FIN = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), Z_FIN = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), .Names = c("FIRM", "WEEKS", "PR_ADMIN", "Z_ADMIN", "PR_MKT", "Z_MKT", "PR_FIN", "Z_FIN"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = c("plm.dim", "data.frame"));
sal.dt <- as.data.table(sal);
prod.dt <- as.data.table(prod);

## solutions
bgoldst <- function(sal,prod) { sufs <- c('ADMIN','MKT','FIN'); slys <- paste0('SLY_',sufs); mins <- max.col(-sal[slys]); res <- merge(prod[,c('FIRM','WEEKS')],cbind(sal[,'FIRM',drop=F],SLY_DEPT=slys[mins],MIN_SLY=sal[slys][cbind(seq_len(nrow(sal)),mins)])); res.sufs <- sub('.*_','',res$SLY_DEPT); for (pre in c('PR','Z')) { pre.cns <- paste0(pre,'_',sufs); res[[pre]] <- prod[pre.cns][cbind(seq_len(nrow(prod)),match(paste0(pre,'_',res.sufs),pre.cns))]; }; res; };
akrun <- function(ANNUALSALARY,WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY) { i1 <- max.col(-1*ANNUALSALARY[,-1,with=F]); dN <- data.table(FIRM= ANNUALSALARY$FIRM, MIN_SLY=as.data.frame(ANNUALSALARY)[-1][cbind(1:nrow(ANNUALSALARY), i1)], SLY_DEPT = names(ANNUALSALARY)[-1][i1]); dN2 <- melt(dN[WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY, on = "FIRM"], measure = patterns("^PR", "^Z"), value.name = c("PR", "Z"))[order(FIRM, variable, WEEKS)][, gr1 := cumsum(WEEKS==1), FIRM][]; res <- data.table(FIRM= ANNUALSALARY$FIRM, i1)[dN2, on = "FIRM"][gr1==i1]; res[,!names(res)%in%c('i1','variable','gr1'),with=F]; };
maximus <- function(ANNUALSALARY,WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY) { res <- WEEKLYPRODUCTIVITY[ANNUALSALARY, on = 'FIRM']; sly.cols <- grep('^SLY_', names(res), value = TRUE); res[, `:=` (MIN_SLY = min(.SD), SLY_DEPT = sly.cols[which.min(.SD)]), by = 1:nrow(res), .SDcols = sly.cols][]; res2 <- melt(res, id = c('FIRM','WEEKS','MIN_SLY','SLY_DEPT'), measure.vars = patterns('^PR_','^Z_'), value.name = c('PR','Z'))[, variable := c('ADMIN','MKT','FIN')[variable]][, `:=` (PR = PR[sub('^SLY_','',SLY_DEPT) == variable], Z = Z[sub('^SLY_','',SLY_DEPT) == variable]), by = .(FIRM,WEEKS)][, variable := NULL]; res2 <- res2[!duplicated(res2)]; };

## proofs of equivalence
ex <- bgoldst(sal,prod); co <- names(ex);
identical(ex,transform(as.data.frame(akrun(sal.dt,prod.dt))[co],SLY_DEPT=factor(SLY_DEPT)));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,transform(as.data.frame(maximus(sal.dt,prod.dt))[co],SLY_DEPT=factor(SLY_DEPT)));
## [1] TRUE

## benchmark
microbenchmark(bgoldst(sal,prod),akrun(sal.dt,prod.dt),maximus(sal.dt,prod.dt));
## Unit: milliseconds
##                      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
##        bgoldst(sal, prod) 1.639193 1.730070 1.883285 1.807047 1.881031  3.230917   100
##    akrun(sal.dt, prod.dt) 6.392125 6.666251 7.744077 6.901033 7.230752 53.621663   100
##  maximus(sal.dt, prod.dt) 5.002254 5.229979 5.853681 5.423492 6.034609 12.182544   100
```

Comment: Thanks for the base R solution. Is there generally any problem when datatables are used with plm package? I had been thinking about this for a long time.

Comment: You're welcome. I've never used the plm package, so I'm the wrong guy to ask. You can try asking akrun, he's very knowledgeable about R.

Comment: nice base R solution!

Comment: @bgoldst Kindly have a look on this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293841/r-matching-aggregate-values-with-daily-values-by-repetition-to-form-panel-datas